# Swift: FCM change sound of notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use this code:

```
let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
let position = userInfo["TITLE"] as? NSString
completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
```

This code play default sound, but i want change it to system files `mysound.mp3`

How i can ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play a custom sound when notification received you will have to add sound key to your notification payload and sound file into xcode project.

Add files to the Xcode project root. Make sure Add to targets is selected when adding files so that they are automatically add to the bundle resources. Sound must be less than 30 seconds.

See below exapmple.

```
   {
        aps =     
        {
            alert = "notification message";
            sound = "example.wav";
        }; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but my users can be select from multiple sound. and i can't handle it from server

Comment: You will have to handle by notification payload coming from server we can not play sound when notification receives without sound key from payload.

Comment: OK. user1 select x.mp3 and user2 select y.mp3. how i can handle it ? i have to save users selected in my database on server and when i send notification set for each users sound ?

Comment: Yes, update your server when user selects sound file from app.